# Получить содержимое тега в таблице, который в ряду, на который указывает мышь

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как на jQuery или JavaScript получить содержимое ячейки, которая находиться в ряду, на который наведен указатель мыши?

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно получить содержимое ячейки, то можно вот так:

```js
var currentTarget;
$("table").mousemove(function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  if (target !== currentTarget && target.tagName === "TD") {
    console.log(target.innerHTML);
    currentTarget = target;
  }
});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Проверка на `target` нужна чтобы когда наведение осуществляется в пределах одной и той же ячейки содержимое не выводилось много раз.